# turn object to face position

Tags: java, libgdx

im trying to work out the angle i need to turn and object so that it faces another. should be fairly easy but im making a mess of it.

I have an array of Vector3's to be used as way points.

I've got the angle in degrees of my vehicle  by coding this.

```
float vehHeading = functions.map(mat.getRotation(rot).nor() .getYaw(),180f,-180f,0,360f) ;
```

and the angle from my Veh to the tgt like this.

```
double WPangle = Math.atan2(paths.get(0).z  - vehPos.z, paths.get(0).x - vehPos.x ) * (180/Math.PI);

float angletoTgt = functions.map((float) WPangle,-180f,180f,360f,0f);
```

What I need to work out is if I need to turn left or right to get the vehicle facing the tgt.

has any one got any ideas?

many thanks

spriggsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a nights sleep i realized how easy this was.

```
float newHeading = vehHeading  - WPangle;
if (newHeading < 0)
    {newHeading = newHeading + 360}
```

now if new heading is less than 180 turn right, else turn left.

works a treat.